# "Двусторонний" или "двухсторонний"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

Comment: Задача для  начинающих психологов

Даны следующие слова:

1) односторонний,

2) двусторонний, двухсторонний,

3) трёхсторонний,

4) четырёхсторонний,

5) пятисторонний,

6) шестисторонний.

Уберите лишнее слово.

Answer (score 10):

То, что толковый словарь даёт оба прилагательных в заголовке одной словарной статьи, говорит об отсутствии **семантических** и **стилистических** различий. Разница же в **употреблении** есть, она заметна в устойчивых (обычно терминологических) сочетаниях – именно они в основном и приведены в словаре: *двустороннее воспаление лёгких, двухстороннее уличное движение, двухстороннее соглашение, двусторонний договор, двусторонняя радиосвязь.* Сюда же можно добавить и другие терминологические сочетания типа *двусторонние переговоры.* Закреплённость в составе этих сочетаний какого-то одного варианта объясняется традицией.

Comment: _двустороннее связывание_

Answer (score 6):

Варианты равноправны.

Большой толковый словарь:

ДВУСТОРОННИЙ; ДВУХСТОРОННИЙ.

1.
Имеющий две стороны; происходящий, производимый, расположенный и т. п. с двух сторон. Двустороннее воспаление лёгких. Двухстороннее уличное движение. 
//С одинаковыми сторонами, без изнанки и лица (о ткани). Д. драп.

2.
Обязательный для обеих сторон; обоюдный. Двухстороннее соглашение. Двусторонний договор. //
Действующий в обе стороны. Двусторонняя радиосвязь.

Comment: т.е.двухстороннее соглашение,но двусторонний договор???не понятно..

Answer (score 3):

В стилистическом словаре вариантов Л. Граудиной, В. Ицковича, Л. Катлинской «Грамматическая правильность русской речи рассмотрены подобные случаи: см. ответ № 172716. 
В «Справочнике по правописанию и литературной правке» Д. Э. Розенталя указано: при наличии обоих вариантов чаще используется *двусторонний*, однако такая дифференциация не имеет категорического характера (в книжных словах может быть элемент *двух-* и, наоборот, в обиходно-разговорных словах - элемент *дву-*.)

©Справка на Грамоте
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_267853  
и еще тут:  
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%E4%E2%F3%F1%F2%EE%F0%EE%ED%ED%E8%E9

Answer (score 2):

Я врач-рентгенолог. Занимаюсь диагностикой заболеваний всех органов и систем. Провожу исследования легких в том числе. И когда делаю заключение о наличии пневмонии, всегда пишу в случае  таковой- ДВУСТОРОННЯЯ! Интуитивно, не помню, чтобы наставники акцентировали на этом, но видимо так и преподавалось, как нечто аксиомное. Во всяком случае, моя  рука не поднимается написать "двух-"! Сегодня, увидев в заключении коллеги формулировку "двухстороняя пневмония",  заглянула к вам на страницу. Убедилась в правильности написания своих умозаключений)))) СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 2):

Пред гласными и йотированными пишется "двух": двухактный, двухэтажный, двухъярусный. Перед согласными чаще всего "х" выпадает: двужильный, двуличный, двусмысленный.

В некоторых сложных словах с использованием элементов "двух/дву" оба варианта считаются равноправными: двухлетний - двулетний; двухсложный - двусложный; двухполый - двуполый. Однако в большинстве случаев правописание прилагательных, образованных таким способом, все-таки требует использования формы числительного "двух": двухлетний, двухтомный, двухкамерный, двухпроцентный. Подробнее:[Как пишется правильно: двухсторонний или двусторонний](http://thedifference.ru/kak-pishetsya-pravilno-dvuxstoronnij-ili-dvustoronnij/)

Answer (score 2):

Образование сложных слов способом соединения основы числительного и полной формы прилагательного подчиняется не только орфографическим, но и орфоэпическим правилам. Их необходимо учитывать при написании слова *двусторонний,* правильность употребления которого на слух определить довольно сложно.

Он содержат элемент *дву-,* который соединяется с прилагательным *сторонний,* образуя сложное слово. Этот вариант является орфографически верным, но его часто смешивают с другим, в котором ошибочно используется элемент *двух-.*

Правилом, определяющим нормативность форм сложных прилагательных, является разграничение гласных, йотированных и согласных звуков на стыке основы числительного и прилагательного.

Пред гласными и йотированными пишется *двух-:* двухактный, двухэтажный, двухъярусный. Перед согласными чаще всего *-х-* выпадает: двужильный, двуличный, двусмысленный.

В некоторых сложных словах с использованием элементов *двух-/дву-* оба варианта считаются равноправными: двухлетний-двулетний; двухсложный-двусложный; двухполый-двуполый. Однако в большинстве случаев правописание прилагательных, образованных таким способом, все-таки требует использования формы числительного *двух-:* двухлетний, двухтомный, двухкамерный, двухпроцентный.

Прилагательное *двусторонний* входит в число сложных слов, в которых не допускается вариант *двух-*. Их следует запомнить или проверять по орфографическим словарям. Это прилагательные *двусторонний, двуглавый, двукратный, двустопный, двуличный, двурогий, двуязычный* и некоторый другие.

В разговорной речи слово *двусторонний* не всегда употребляется правильно. Нарушение орфоэпической нормы при произношении *двухсторонний* приводит к орфографической ошибке в его написании.

Подробнее:

http://thedifference.ru/kak-pishetsya-pravilno-dvuxstoronnij-ili-dvustoronnij/

Comment: Татьяна, милая Татьяна! Я филолог с 37-летним стажем; уверяю Вас: многие языковые вопросы решаются голосованием. Я уберу в Вашем достойнейшем ответе эмоции (это именно в ответе кагбэ не комильфо) и слегка подредактирую. Удачи на проекте!

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, "двух-" употребляется, когда это относится к двум разным предметам: например, две стороны соглашения не являются чем-то целым. А "дву-" к одному: например, договор, воспаление, бумага (с наличием рисунка), движение, связь... Думаю, что такое объяснение логично и просто, хотя я юрист, а не лингвист :)